# Defining array with multiple types in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array of the form: `[ 1, "message" ]`.

How would I define this in TypeScript?

Comment: Similar question to this one, with no answer, but this time using class inheritance with unknown number of items and all extending the same class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322488/array-of-unknown-size-with-items-of-different-classes-that-extends-the-same-pare

Answer (score 809, accepted):

> Defining array with multiple types in TypeScript

Use a union type `(string|number)[]` demo:

```
const foo: (string|number)[] = [ 1, "message" ];
```

> I have an array of the form: [ 1, "message" ].

If you are sure that there are always only two elements `[number, string]` then you can declare it as a tuple:

```
const foo: [number, string] = [ 1, "message" ];
```

And you can even provide meaningful names for the tuple members e.g. `id` and `text`:

```
const foo: [id: number, text: string] = [ 1, "message" ];
```

Comment: Just a note that this will require TS v1.4+

Comment: ... and it won't work with complex types with different properties, when you want to access a property available on only one of the types.

Comment: @Nadine And in that case, what could one do?

Comment: Each time when you are clear about which type it is, you can do a type assertion. Then it will work to access the properties.

Comment: Good point @seawave_23, I suggest you edit the accepted answer with this information if possible

Answer (score 111):

If you're treating it as a tuple (see section 3.3.3 of the [language spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.3.3)), then:

```
var t:[number, string] = [1, "message"]
```

or

```
interface NumberStringTuple extends Array<string|number>{0:number; 1:string}
var t:NumberStringTuple = [1, "message"];
```

Comment: TIP: I would prefer `type NumberStringTuple = [number, string]`

Comment: Thanks! I was totally looking for this: `const W3COLORS: [[string, string, number, number]] = [    ["aliceblue", "#f0f8ff", 240, 248, 255], ... ];`

Comment: Note - both types MUST be in the array (doesn't work for an empty array as well). Accepted answer is more versatile and which I personally always use, but it depends on the needs.

Answer (score 58):

My TS lint was complaining about other solutions, so the solution that was working for me was:

```
item: Array<Type1 | Type2>
```

if there's only one type, it's fine to use:

```
item: Type1[]
```

Comment: This is great, but say if we're looping over the array now, how do we figure out which type the current array is?

Comment: @thouliha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774790/switch-for-specific-type-in-typescript

Answer (score 42):

**TypeScript 3.9+ update (May 12, 2020)**

Now, TypeScript also supports ***named tuples***. This greatly increases the *understandability* and *maintainability* of the code. [Check the official TS playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#example/named-tuples)

---

So, now instead of unnamed:

```
const a: [number, string] = [ 1, "message" ];
```

**We can add names:**

```
const b: [id: number, message: string] = [ 1, "message" ];
```

---

**Note**: you need to add all names at once, you can not omit some names, e.g:

```
type tIncorrect = [id: number, string]; // INCORRECT, 2nd element has no name, compile-time error.
type tCorrect = [id: number, msg: string]; // CORRECT, all have a names.
```

**Tip**: if you are not sure in the count of the last elements, you can write it like this:

```
type t = [msg: string, ...indexes: number];// means first element is a message and there are unknown number of indexes.
```

**TypeScript 4.x+ Variadic Tuple Types**

The last example has to be changed to this one for TS 4.x:

```
type t = [msg: string, ...indexes: number[]];// means first element is a message and there are unknown number of indexes.
```

The type `number` is changed to `number[]`.

More info here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types

Comment: What is it for? The names on tuple elements?

Comment: @Marecky it was added for ease of use, e.g. hint from TypeScript compiler: `(property) 0: number (id)` instead of unified `(property) 0: number`. So, there will be more details in the error message too, if any.

Answer (score 27):

I've settled on the following format for typing arrays that can have items of multiple types.

`Array<ItemType1 | ItemType2 | ItemType3>`

This works well with testing and type guards. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

This format doesn't work well with testing or type guards:

`(ItemType1 | ItemType2 | ItemType3)[]`

Answer (score 7):

Im using this version:

```
exampleArr: Array<{ id: number, msg: string}> = [
   { id: 1, msg: 'message'},
   { id: 2, msg: 'message2'}
 ]
```

It is a little bit similar to the other suggestions but still easy and quite good to remember.

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in getting an array of either numbers or strings, you could define a type that will take an array of either

```
type Tuple = Array<number | string>
const example: Tuple = [1, "message"]
const example2: Tuple = ["message", 1]
```

If you expect an array of a specific order (i.e. number and a string)

```
type Tuple = [number, string]
const example: Tuple = [1, "message"]
const example2: Tuple = ["messsage", 1] // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Answer (score 5):

```
const myarray:(TypeA | TypeB)[];
```

or even better to avoid changes in multiple place in case you need to add another type, create type

```
type MyMixedType = TypeA | TypeB;
const myarray: MyMixedType[];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ 1, "message" ] as const ;
```

if you do "as const" , type will be

```
type const = readonly [1, "message"]
```

It is good because of the exact type inference that computer can possible.

Answer (score 0):

If dealing with an array with multiple value types in an object this worked for me.

```
 { [key: string]: number | string }[]
```