# Array of unknown size with items of different classes that extends the same parent class

Tags: typescript

Basically want to declare an array which contains arbitrary number of items which types are sub classes of the same base class. I don't know how many sub classes are (some could be provided by third party plugins). If I declare the array like `Array<BaseClass>` I expect exact type checking for each literal item object declaration but typescript is forcing me to cast in order to type check. Nor me or my users expect casting because of class polymorphism.

Example:

```
class Base {
  name: string
}
class Sub1 extends Base {
  prop1: number
}
class Sub2 extends Base {
  prop2:string
}
// there will be other Base subclasses - I don't know how much - some provided by third party plugins

// public function called by end users - I want exact type checking of items object literals and I don't expect to manually cast each of them as in the example: 

function f(arr: Base[]){
}

// This doesn't work: for some reason typescript assumes every item is of type Sub1 even if I explicitly declared the second item as Sub2 : 
f([
  {name: '1', prop1: 1} as Sub1, 
  {name: '1', prop2: '2'} as Sub2, 
])

// This does does work and do exact typechecking as I want but I still need to cast (and I don't think I should)

f([
  {name: '1', prop1: 1},
  {name: '1', prop2: '2'},
] as [Sub1, Sub2])
```

In a similar situation, typescript perform a perfect job. This is when calling an overloaded method or function. I don't need to cast and typescript is able to exactly match the signature wihtout having to cast enything .I wonder if for arrays they didn't want to implement "this automatic item inferring") because of performance (there could be huge (json) arrays)...

The only elegant way for users to call `f()` is by casting each array item. I don't want my library's users to be force to do that. Is non hard and non obvious.

Is there a way of users calling f() without having to cast and with exact typechecking ?  In an object oriented language, because of class polymorphism, since Sub1 and Sub2 ARE instances of Base, me (and my users) DONT EXPECT TO CAST HERE.

Note: Because I don't know all Base subclasses (some could be provided by third parties), I cannot define f argument using type union (`arr: Array<Sub1|Sub2>`)

In other languages like Java, you declare the array like this: `Array<? extends Base>` - maybe typescript has something similar I'm missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is one that is designed to catch typos. The most common reason it triggers is for a mis-spelled property. This check only applies to object initialization.

If you have an existing array, the function will be happy to accept it as long as it has a `name` property.

```
var arr = [
    { name: '1', prop1: 1 },
    { name: '1', prop2: '2' }
];

f(arr);
```

## More Things

If you are dealing more with cases where the items will be created you can tell the compiler to expect more things:

```
class Base {
    name: string;
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

This makes it transparent to the compiler that...

*There will definitely be a name... and there might be some other properties too.*

## Intersection Type

If you don't want to spoil your `Base` class, you can use the following trick by creating an intersection type using both `Base` and a separate `Indexed` type.

```
class Base {
    name: string;
}

type Indexed = { [key: string]: any; }

// ...

function f(...arr: (Base & Indexed)[]) {
}

// ...
```

## Give it a Name

One final tidy up you might want to do is give the intersection type a name. If you are going to use it in multiple places this helps tidy things up a bit.

```
// ...

type SubOfBase = Base & Indexed;

function f(...arr: SubOfBase[]) {
}
```

Comment: Hello Fenton, thanks for taking the time to explain this. I'm not trying to solve an error, I'm trying to have strict type checking on array literals wich arbitrary number of items which are of different sub classes of a base class. I found a better way that does exact type-checking but I still need to cast. Since all array items are of sub classes of the same base, I don't expect to cast to have exact type-checking. I expect typescript to  infer each array member literal exact type. Perhaps this is not supported because performance, but currently is well supported in method overloaded calls