# Switch for specific type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface `Action`:

```
interface Action {}
```

And an implementation of this `Action` `SpecificAction`:

```
class SpecificAction implements Action {
   payload?: Any
}
```

Is it possible in TS to construct a switch operator, like this:

```
let action: Action
switch (action) {
   case SpecificAction: //it works
       console.log(action.payload) // it doesn't 
}
```

Is it possible in that case to know, that action is already of `SpecificAction` type?

Comment: Could you use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions)?

Comment: I could, but I don't really see how it is better. I will still have to check some property instead of type itself

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko yes you will still have to check some property, but that is what the compiler supports for switch and type guards

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, fair enough)

Comment: Is `action` in practice an instance of a class that implements `Action`, or could it just be a regular object? If the former, did my answer help, or did I misunderstand what you were looking for?

Comment: @pushkin, I didn't downvote it (just in case)

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko Oh no, I didn't suspect that you did, I was just curious if that's what you were looking for, or no.

Comment: although your answer didn't bring a lot for solving my issue, I can see how it tries to answer it. so I don't see a reason for downvote either

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko If my answer didn't help, then you don't need to upvote. I'm just curious *why* it didn't help. If your point is that you want to do this with a `switch`, then I don't think that's possible (unless you opt for what's done in jonrsharpe's link; switch on a `kind` property). If not that, then I think you'd have to do what I state in my answer.

Comment: @VladyslavZavalykhatko RE "I will still have to check some property instead of type itself": https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-check-at-run-time-if-an-object-implements-some-interface

Answer (score 52, accepted):

for the time being it looks like there are a few options, all of them with some drawbacks

- discriminated unions ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-union-types)), but you'll need a dedicated property as discriminator

```
interface Action {}

class SpecificAction implements Action {
  kind: "specific";
  payload?: any;
}

class ToggleAction implements Action {
  kind: "toggle";
  toggle: boolean;
}

let action: SpecificAction | ToggleAction;
switch (action.kind) {
  case "specific":
    console.log(action.payload) // it works 
    break;
  case "toggle":
    console.log(action.toggle) // it works 
    break;        
}
```

- User-Defined Type Guards ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#User-Defined-Type-Guards), [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-user-defined-guards)), but you'll need if statements instead of switch

```
interface Action {}

class SpecificAction implements Action {
  payload?: any;
}

class ToggleAction implements Action {
  toggle: boolean;
}

let isSpecific = (p: any): p is SpecificAction => !!p.payload
let isToggle = (p: any): p is ToggleAction => !!p.toggle

let action: Action;
if (isSpecific(action)) {
  console.log(action.payload) // it works 
} else if (isToggle(action)) {
  console.log(action.toggle) // it works 
}
```

- constructor property ([github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23274), [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-constructor-comparison)), but you'll need to cast to desired type for the time being

```
interface Action { }

class SpecificAction implements Action {
  payload?: any;
}

class ToggleAction implements Action {
  toggle: boolean;
}

switch (action.constructor) {
  case SpecificAction:
    console.log((<SpecificAction>action).payload) // it kinda works 
    break;
  case ToggleAction:
    console.log((<ToggleAction>action).toggle) // it kinda works 
    break;
  }
```

Comment: An empty `interface` is nonsensical in typescript as it in no way unifies implementers as evidenced by the optional nature of the `implements` clause.

Comment: i'm pretty sure we miss some context in the original question, but for completeness i guess this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure 
should help any future reader for that matter

Comment: Switching with constructor is my preferred way but be aware that this may not work in special cases, for example consider this one:

export class Response { 
  static Success = class extends Response { } 
}

console.log(new Response.Success().constructor);
console.log(new Response().constructor);

Answer (score 9):

You'd be better off using an `if` statement with typeguards.

```
let action: Action = ...;
if (isSpecificAction(action)) {
    console.log(action.payload);
}

function isSpecificAction(action: any): action is SpecificAction {
    return action.payload;
}
```

At the end of the day, TypeScript is still JavaScripty, and the `switch` statement gets transpiled to a regular JS [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch):

> A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as the result of the input expression (using the strict comparison, ===)

So in your case:

```
interface Action {}
class SpecificAction implements Action {
   payload?: any
}

let action: Action
switch (action) {
   case SpecificAction: //it works
       console.log(action.payload) // it doesn't 
}
```

`action` would be evaluated and compared with *the class* `SpecificAction`. Presumably, `action` is an *instance* of `SpecificAction` (or some object that implements the `Action` interface).

With a `switch`, you could do this:

```
let a: Action = new SpecificAction();
let b: Action = a;

switch (a) {
    case b:
        console.log("Worked");
}
```

The expression `a` is evaluated and compared to the expression `b` (and `a === b`, so we hit the `console.log`), but that's obviously not what you're looking for.

If you want to check if an instance is of a particular type (re: class), then you should use a type guard. A `switch/case` is the wrong construct.

---

Alternatively, why not use `instanceof`?

```
interface Action { };
class SpecificAction implements Action {}
class NotSpecificAction implements Action {}

let action: Action = new SpecificAction();
console.log(action instanceof SpecificAction); // true
console.log(action instanceof NotSpecificAction); // false
```

Comment: Does this not answer the question, or are there technical inaccuracies? (curious about the downvote)

Comment: This is an excellent answer but it's worth pointing out the misunderstanding evident in the use of the marker interface in the OP as opposed to repeating it. An empty interface is nonsensical in typescript as it in no way unifies implementers as evidenced by the optional nature of the implements clause

Comment: @AluanHaddad The marker interface may just be a minimal example. It's quite possible that his actual `Action` interface has more to offer

Comment: that's possible but given the nature and phrasing of the question, I think it is important to point out. Many people don't understand type erasure, and are confused by this. I would write my own answer, but I like yours. +1 regardless