# How can I detect a class instance with generics in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, generics, instance, inference

I'm trying to create a function that takes two parameters, the first is the class reference and the second is a function with only one parameter that is an instance of the class reference and the output is a specific type.
I tried the code below, but the typescript shows me an unknown type for p, even though I hope p was an instance of Pair.

```
interface Point{
    x: number
    y: number
}
class Pair{
    key = 0
    value = 0
}
function set<Class extends { new (): Type }, Type>(
    inputClass: Class,
    constructor: (o: Type) => Point) {
    //implementation...
}
set(Pair, p => ({x: p.key, y: p.value}))
// Typescript says:
// (parameter) p: unknown
// Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571)
```

I wanted the typescript to know that p must be an instance of Pair

---

I was able to implement using java generics, but I still can't replicate in typescript. Follow the code:

```
public <K extends Pair, T extends Class<K>> void setRenderer(T classe, Function<K, Point> constructor){
    //implementation
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
function set<C>(
    inputClass: new ()=>C,
    constructor: (o: C) => Point) {
    //implementation...
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRgN4FgBQyRyAHgFzIgCuAtgEbQHHICeF19j+AvgQgDZwAzkLRxgUPIWIBrCC2QBeZAAYmxAG5x+VFMrU8CMKiARhg6EMiEQwAHgDCAPgAU6oqAAOVMA8Ej2CAB3ZBcASkUnBwAad2QESyEwKCozdCgKF3QKBzClJzRMcDypZgB6MuAaT34IGghwOHNLADo2gl58GzAXVHEoaORPfNDsciGWuRZBtgmtHQhuMLCCCuQAFRZPCCEEKGBPMGs4FiEyVbLQzzgoOHrIKDzPChMZEHQgkAvkAHk6ACsIGZkMBROgYMgwFsUAByV7vT4wlouABMAFYAOwARjCQA)

Answer (score 1):

Generics don't work like this, type inference doesn't go this way.

Simple solution:

```js
interface Point{
    x: number
    y: number
}
class Pair{
    key = 0
    value = 0
}
declare function set<Type>(constructor: (o: Type) => Point): void;

set<Pair>(p => ({ x: p.key, y: p.value }))
```

Or if you really want to pass in the class:

```js
interface Point{
    x: number
    y: number
}
class Pair{
    key = 0
    value = 0
}
function set<Type>(
    inputClass: { new (): Type },
    constructor: (o: Type) => Point) {
    //implementation...
}
set(Pair, p => ({ x: p.key, y: p.value }))
```

Comment: Thanks, the second way works for me. In that case, I really need the class as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure why you need classes here.

You could achieve what you're looking for with interfaces, like this:

```
interface Point{
    x: number
    y: number
}

interface Pair{
    key:number
    value:number
}
const instance: Pair = {
    key : 0,
    value : 0
}

function set(value: Pair):Point {
    return  ({x: value.key, y: value.value})
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAUD24IG9iqGoAeAXKmAK4C2ARrAUQJ7lV0MC%20woksiKGBCBj4iqANZQWbejEaEAbggA2lKKRmdgSTGADOEVOAMIwKcuiExUAXlSiikpqnIAGADTzUS1WjfAuMW1dA1Q9KEMbAAofNQsrAEpSLBxbAD5UL0Io3DJvFTUAOid3VBZ830LYqA4E7iA)

Or if you really do want classes you can do the following:

[Class Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=7&pln=12&pc=15#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAUD24IG9iqGoAeAXKmAK4C2ARrAUQJ7lV0MC%20wwSANggGcBGBCBj4iqANZQmqALyoADI0IA3BL0ppFKrj0xgBEVOGMIwKculEwFqCURlzySgDSrUGrWlfAukgZGJgJQJvIAFN7a1rYAlKRYOAoAfKiehBG4ZF6a2gB0zm6oLLk%20%20dFQHHHcoRARZhAWKHFAA)

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I need something more dynamic, something that I can infer from the class reference. My objective is to create a Map associating Classes and their respective builders.
Something like new Map <T, (a: T) => Point>.

Comment: so T will vary? You may wish to update your question a little. Perhaps you are tying to do something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774790/switch-for-specific-type-in-typescript