# How can TypeScript infer types from an array containing different types?

Tags: typescript

I am trying use an array containing multiple different types and have TypeScript infer the proper type for each element:

```
type House = {
    street: string;
    zipCode: number;
}

type Car = {
    make: string;
    model: string;
    year: number
}

const things: (House | Car)[] = [{
    street: '123 Fake Street',
    zipCode: 12345
}, {
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'Model X',
    year: 2022
},
{
    /* any other 'Car' or 'House' */
}]

things[1].year; // <---- Why doesn't TypeScript know it is a "Car" type and shows me an error here?
```

Is there an easy way to help TypeScript with knowing the type without explicitly casting the array element?

Comment: It seems like you actually want a tuple type. You're _explicilty_ saying that any item in that array is either a House or a Car, so of course the compiler complains.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually, it's not about a tuple (I updated my code sample), but about an array of any number of elements. For example, I would like to iterate through this array and have Typescript automatically infer the type for each of the elements (whether it's a 'Car' or a 'House').

Comment: Well it's simply not going to do that. Array types have values of the same type at any and every index. Only tuples track the type by index.

Comment: It will if you help it. LOL. Going after the *goal* of the question (how to call `things[x].year`) leads to some possibilities. If you type check the value first, then TypeScript can infer it correctly. :-)

Comment: @DeborahK you can provide more information, sure, but that's **not** the same thing as inference.

Answer (score 1):

Since the array is typed as `(House | Car)[]`, the compiler will let you add as many Houses or Cars to the array, in any position. So, during the compile step, it's unknown whether the item at any specific index is a `House` or a `Car`.

However, the compiler *is* smart enough to infer the type of an object if you check (during *runtime*) [for the existence of a property that only exists on one of the possible types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing).

In your example, only `Car` has the `make` property, while `House` does not. So checking `"make" in item` confirms that `item` is a `Car`.

```
const item: House | Car = things[1];
if ("make" in item) {
    // the compiler is satisfied that item is a Car inside this block,
    // because only Cars have the "make" property
    item.year // <-- no error
}
```

Another useful pattern here is the [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions). You would declare your types like this:

```
type House = {
    kind: "house";
    street: string;
    zipCode: number;
}

type Car = {
    kind: "car";
    make: string;
    model: string;
    year: number
}
```

By checking the value of the `kind` property, the compiler is then satisfied which type of item you are looking at:

```
const item: House | Car = things[1];
if (item.kind === "car") {
   item.year // <-- no error
} else {
   item.street // <-- no error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked how TypeScript can infer types from an array containing different types. It can infer the types if you give it a little help and type check it first.

If you use a type guard to check the type as shown in this example, then TypeScript will correctly understand the type, and even provide the dropdown list of properties in the IDE.

```
function isSpecificType(item: House | Car): item is Car {
    return true;
}

if (isSpecificType(things[1])) {
  console.log(things[1].year)
} else  {
  console.log(things[1].street)
}
```

Based on the info from here: [Switch for specific type in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50774790/switch-for-specific-type-in-typescript)

There is also some useful information on type guards here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: I didn't vote it down, but this doesn't seem to answer the question. OP wants the compiler to infer the type automatically, which isn't possible for unbounded arrays. This would be the next best tradeoff solution.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I guess it depends on how the question is interpreted. I read `How can TypeScript infer types from an array containing different types?` as wanting to figure out a way to call `*.year` on any of the elements. I believe this solution would meet that requirement. :-)

Comment: Type guards aren't really inference, but rather type assertions with logic. But yeah, this is the best you can do currently.

Answer (score 0):

bunch of different ways to do this, i'd recommend either a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) or a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)

[Check out this TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEg9gVwM7QLxQN4FgBQV9RLABOEEwAXISQJYB2A5gNy4FQBeNYAwnACYQqdBAFsARhGIscAX1y5QkKNwCGxKOmx4CIlQGtB1YvWasd-CABsqRY42lsQENUNETiuOTlwBjOHSIoYAALEyQAQSoAbXhkCAAaZTUAXQ0oKK02WzJKKAByAEYAJgBmKAAxfWgAZRIcvPizfE4eCypikoAWAFZPRMydKqo8gBUIJEsVBqaoEQtrfIBZeagADWntfCcXKCKABiKiz2T5HEtyKBVYlDSQsPCovZOzi5VVdXQ7xgiogueAen+UAAAsAkABaCAAD0gPmAkOIxDgHhewEuAFFEcjbqFvg8is9Tn4AmivgwkAAhNIZGbZcjDDoVKpQWqkcgbNgtXgCdqlHp9TAzXQGYZjCZTRqbWbzYbLASWNYcgjbYhUfaHY6XJBQYlEU7nNFia6GY04sIUx7PA1QMTvKjvM3fC1-XCAkFgyEwiBwhFIlHWsSYv32tSO8kWp64IA) for an interactive example with the following code:

```
type House = {
    street: string;
    zipCode: number;
}

type Car = {
    make: string;
    model: string;
    year: number
}

const thingsA: [House, Car] = [{
    street: '123 Fake Street',
    zipCode: 12345
}, {
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'Model X',
    year: 2022
}]

let aHouse = thingsA[0]
let aCar = thingsA[1]
// @ts-expect-error
let aError = thingsA[2]


const thingsB = [{
    street: '123 Fake Street',
    zipCode: 12345
}, {
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'Model X',
    year: 2022
}] as const

let bHouse: House = thingsB[0]
let bCar: Car = thingsB[1]
// @ts-expect-error
let bError: Car = thingsB[0]
```

with real data, i find tagged unions aka discriminated unions (aka ADTs?)  to be  the best way to deal with this

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEg9gVwM7QLxQN4FgBQV9QD6wAhgOYBcUARABaIrUDcuBUSwAThBMFR5wCWAOzIs8BAF6CwAYTgATCFWEIAtgCMIncQF9cuUJCiySnKOmwT8xclWoBjM9QA0rAmpIBrZey4ixd3w1RQgAG35-UXE2EAgzFXUtTlx9HFwHOGEOKGBaAKQAQSpCzk4SEAAeeGQIAB9TTgA+CygAbSsbUkoaelrXIL9uXioAcgBGACYAZigAMW9oAGUuHmBRt2soaTlQqinpgBYAVlSXTHdbHsdnTbZPHzGAFQgkMJINwZClCKhRgFlQmEoAANT5bOIJKCTAAMk0mqQAugZ0jgAGZwcwACky2WAuXyoigcDRBIKhQAlBcJEgAO6CYAOWhQLF5AIAOiuFM6BCcKF6DAg1CoPLYAHoxVBhHBaVBadAvNLZQzRkgoCQoH0UOydYN8LikHAwhB2WE4GRWYSyOyBGsKXqoBpuN5Bmk2HzoDdOMLqWx8BKpTK5QqlVAVWqNU5ODr2Q6DUaTWaLWzROzvuF7Vt8E74l5Xe40mkgA)

```
type House = {
    _tag: "house";
    street: string;
    zipCode: number;
}

type Car = {
    _tag: "car",
    make: string;
    model: string;
    year: number
}

const thingsA: Array<House|Car> = [{
    _tag: "house",
    street: '123 Fake Street',
    zipCode: 12345
}, {
    _tag: "car",
    make: 'Tesla',
    model: 'Model X',
    year: 2022
}]


for (const thing of thingsA) {
  switch (thing._tag){
    case "house": {
      // now we know it's a house...
      console.log(thing.street)
      break
    }
    case "car": {
      // now we know it's a car...
      console.log(thing.model)
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"(aka ADTs?)"* - ADT means [something different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type).

Comment: @kaya3 from that link

"Two common classes of algebraic types are product types (i.e., tuples and records) and sum types (i.e., tagged or disjoint unions, coproduct types or variant types)."

Comment: @kaya3 oh, nvm, i was looking at a different link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type