# Typing an array of an explicit set of value types

Tags: typescript

Im trying to figure out how to define a type for the following value in TypeScript:

```
[{"source": "bar"}, 1483228800, 1484265600]
```

The only way I have come up with so far is:

```
interface FieldSource {
  source: string;
}

interface SearchWhereClause {
  between: [FieldSource, number, number]
}
```

This compiles fine, but I am unsure if this is the right way.

I have seen I can do:

```
(FieldSource | number | number)[]
```

But in my case I explicitly want the array to contain my object and two number values.

Can someone please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @hereticMonkey mentioned in the comment of the question, this is largely a duplicate of [Defining array with multiple types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382389/defining-array-with-multiple-types-in-typescript)

Specifically for your question, since you are looking for an explicit set. Tuple is the answer.

`(FieldSource | number | number)[]` is the same as `Array<FieldSource | number | number>` meaning it is an arbitrarily long array and can take those types as items in any order.

A side note is that I would suggest using `type FieldSource = { source: string }` over `interface` unless you will use it in class.
It is a much more powerful, straight forward, and flexible construct comparing to `interface`.

Comment: "I would suggest using `type FieldSource = { source: string }` over interface"  you should include your rationale for this

Answer (score 1):

> But in my case I explicitly want the array to contain my object and two number values

If that is truly what you want then your current approach is 100% correct, with the caveat being that the types in that array must appear in that order.

`(FieldSource | number )[]` is very different from `[FieldSource, number, number]`), consider the following:

```
interface MyInterface {
  prop: number
}

type MyTuple = [MyInterface, number, number]
type MyArr = (MyInterface | number)[]

const myTup: MyTuple = [{ prop: 2 }, 2, 2] // <-- can only have two numbers
const myArr: MyArr = [{ prop: 2 }, 2, 2, 2, 2] // <-- can have any amount of numbers
const myArrAsTup: MyTuple = [{ prop: 2 }, 2, 2, 2, 2] // <-- not assignable to type
```

`(FieldSource | number )[]`, which is identical to `(FieldSource | number | number)[]`, is saying that the array can contain either of those values in any order and of any amount.

`[FieldSource, number, number]` is called a [Tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html), and it allows you to enforce both the types allowed in an array, as well as the positions of those types and the length of the array.

```
type MyTuple = [MyInterface, number, number]

const tupleOne: MyTuple = [2, 2, {prop: 2} ] // <-- not assignable
const tupleTwo: MyTuple = [2, {prop: 2}, 2] // <-- not assignable
```

This also allows typescript to easily infer the types of entities retrieved from the array via indexing or destructuring:

```
const [interfaceInstance] = myTup // <-- type is MyInterface
const aNumber = myTup[1] // <-- type is number
```

If you cant ensure the type order (or don't want to), you can always use a union on multiple tuples:

```
// less verbose, worse inference
type TupleMember = (MyInterface | number)
type MyTuple = [TupleMember, TupleMember, TupleMember]

// more verbose, can still infer types of tuple members
// as long as those tuples are created somewhere in your codebase
// and not the result of something else, like an API call
type MyTuple = 
  [MyInterface, number, number] |
  [number, MyInterface, number] |
  [number, number, MyInterface]
```