# How do I represent a two-dimensional array containing multiple types in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm studying TypeScript.

I had a question while studying

```js
const arr = [['192.168.0.1', 1234], ['192.168.0.2', 5678], ...];
```

How do I include different types in a two-dimensional array like the one above?
It would be nice to use 'any', but I don't recommend it in the official documentation.

Comment: You want an array of [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) like `Array<[string, number]>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining array with multiple types in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382389/defining-array-with-multiple-types-in-typescript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use union types in TypeScript. From the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types):

> A union type describes a value that can be one of several types. We
>   use the vertical bar (|) to separate each type, so number | string |
>   boolean is the type of a value that can be a number, a string, or a
>   boolean.

So, in your case, you can declare the array as:

```
const arr: Array<(string | number)[]> = [['192.168.0.1', 1234], ['192.168.0.2', 5678], ...];
```