# How to determine type of variable in typescript, array of numbers or array of strings?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable like

```
const data = [];
```

In some places in my App, data looks like string array or number array

```
// data [1, 2, 3]
// data ["1", "2", "3"]
```

How can I get the type of this variable - type string array or number array ?

Comment: Is it possible to have both numbers and strings in an array ?

Comment: It seems like you have *different* data in it at different points. Settle on just one - whatever makes sense for your use-case, then give the variable *that* type and then ensure you only have one type going into it. For example, if you declare it to be `number[]` then convert all input to numeric before adding into the array.

Comment: @RomiHalasz Yes, no real problem with that `["hello", 42, true]` is valid.

Comment: @RomiHalasz
No only number or only string.

Comment: @0xD34F _Array of numbers or array of strings_ - `string[] | number[]`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can type your variables with a single type

```js
// type data as an array of strings
const data: string[] = [];

// type data as an array of numbers
const data: number[] = [];

// type data as an array of objects
const data: object[] = [];
```

If you want to use a mix of types in your array, you can type it as `any`. But this may not be a good practise.

```js
const data: any[] = [];
```

For more information about type in typescript, look here:
[Basic type documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

For defining array with multiple types, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382420/1934484

Comment: This is what I need.
But how to specify only lines or only numbers together?

Comment: @0xD34F look here if you want to use multiple types https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382420/1934484

Answer (score 2):

You can define your array like this the typescript compiler will only allow strings

```
const array: Array<string> = [];
```

or if you want to have strings and numbers define it like this

```
const array: Array<string | number> = [];
```

You can also define it this way

```
const array: string[] = [];
const array: (string | number)[] = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tomas Vancoillie has the right idea.

You can declare them with the : operator.

You can also infer the type with Array(), for example:

```
let myStringArray = Array<string>();
```

Comment: if specify Array<string | number>   

Will it be (1) only strings and only numbers? Or (2)strings and numbers?

Comment: @0xD34F strings and numbers.

Comment: Array is of Type T, which means , it will be strings and numbers.

Comment: @Paul
How to set type T ?

Comment: @0xD34F T means generic, it accepts everything. If you want to use anything, use the type <any>

Comment: @0xD34F https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html check this out.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/what-s-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-ar)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to get the type of the elements in the, since they are either `string` or `number`, you can just get the type of the first element, since all other elements have the same type:

`typeof data[0] // string or number`