# Typescript type check for an array with mixed types and mixed generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following setup

```
interface Animal<T> {
  name: string;
  makeNoise: () => T;
}

enum DogNoise {
  'bark',
}
class Dog implements Animal<DogNoise> {
  name: 'goodboy';
  makeNoise() {
    return DogNoise.bark;
  }
}

enum CatNoise {
  'meow',
  'purr',
}
class Cat implements Animal<CatNoise> {
  name: 'needy';
  makeNoise() {
    return CatNoise.meow;
  }
}

// what is the correct way to define generic for a mixed array
// knowing that other types of animals could be used (e.g. Cow) is using array the best approach to store them
const pets: Animal<any>[] = [new Cat(), new Dog()];

for (const pet of pets) {
  // now makeNoise returns any
  console.log(pet.makeNoise());
}
```

How can I write a type definition for `animals` such that `pet.makeNoise()` returns the right type?
Could this perhaps be achieved by using something other than an array to store `animals`, or maybe this approach to solving the problem is not the best?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use union type as in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382389/defining-array-with-multiple-types-in-typescript)

In your case :

Animal<CatNoise|DogNoise>